# Issue with SystemWrapper and Castle Windsor

Tags: c#, .net, castle-windsor, ioc-container, systemwrapper

I have being trying to use SystemWrapper to be able to mock file IO and other standard MS methods that I was writing my own wrappers for. However, I find that Castle Windsor, the IOC I am using, is having issues with it.

I am specifically working with IDirectoryInfo and DirectoryInfoWrap which implements it. I have registered like any other interface:

```
container.Register(Component.For<IDirectoryInfo, DirectoryInfoWrap>());
```

I have even done like this:

```
container.Register(Component.For<IDirectoryInfo>().ImplementedBy<DirectoryInfoWrap>());
```

But when I run my application I get this:

> Can't create component 'SystemWrapper.IO.DirectoryInfoWrap' as it has
>   dependencies to be satisfied.
>
> 'SystemWrapper.IO.DirectoryInfoWrap' is waiting for the following
>   dependencies:
>   - Service 'System.IO.DirectoryInfo' which was not registered.
>   - Parameter 'path' which was not provided. Did you forget to set the dependency?

This make no sense to me. Why is it thinking the regular DIrectoryInfo is a "service" that needs to be registered? For giggles I tried registering DirectoryInfo with DirectoryInfoWrap but that gave me this:

> Types System.IO.DirectoryInfo and SystemWrapper.IO.DirectoryInfoWrap
>   are unrelated. That is not allowed. Are you sure you want to make them
>   both services on the same component? Parameter name: x

If anyone has worked this out before please let me know. If it can't be then I will just continue writing wrappers by hand.

Thanks

Comment: Start with familiarising yourself with the concepts and vocabulary. This will help, not just with this one issue but in continued usage: https://github.com/castleproject/Windsor/blob/master/docs/services-and-components.md

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the answer was simple. The System Wrap constructor required a DirectoryInfo parameter. I've never dealt with a constructor parameter with Windsor. After researching that this was the solution:

```
Component.For<IDirectoryInfo, DirectoryInfoWrap>().DependsOn(Dependency.OnValue("directoryInfo", directoryInfo)
```